# The multi-part identifier could not be bound error, despite both the servers have already been linked

Tags: sql-server

Trying to update data from one server to the server. There are 3 columns: Year, Site and Code that need to be updated from my current server to Server2, however I keep on getting the error of "The multi-part identifier could not be bound." Below is my query:

```
UPDATE [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log]
SET
[Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Year] = Poll.[Year],
[Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Site] = Poll.[Site],
[Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Code] = Poll.[Code]
FROM (SELECT Year, Site, Code
    FROM sacfindb.[UC_POLog].[dbo].[ctbl.Main.Report]
    WHERE Year = left(convert(varchar,getdate(),126),7)
        AND Site = '7115'
        AND Code IN (
            '52120','52140','52147','52146','52182'
        )
    ) Poll
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think you can fully qualify the server you are on. So if you say the server you are on is sacfinddb, remove that db name from the query:

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. You only use fully qualified servername.dbname.schemaname.objectname to get to the linked server data. Do not use servername for the server you are executing the query on.

```
UPDATE [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log] 
SET [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Year] = Poll.[Year],
    [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Site] = Poll.[Site],
    [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Code] = Poll.[Code] 
FROM 
(
    SELECT Year, Site, Code  
    FROM [UC_POLog].[dbo].[ctbl.Main.Report] 
    WHERE Year = left(convert(varchar,getdate(),126),7) AND Site = '7115' AND Code in ('52120','52140','52147','52146','52182')
) Poll
```

Comment: sacfindb, this is an internal server on the production server, so it not the main server being used. This query works using the internal server,                    
SELECT Year, Site, Code

FROM sacfindb . [UC_POLog] . [dbo] . [ctbl.Main.Report]

WHERE Year = left(convert(varchar,getdate(),126),7)

AND Site = '7115'

and Code in (

'52120','52140','52147','52146','52182'

)

Comment: SELECT Year, Site, Code                                                                           FROM sacfindb . [UC_POLog] . [dbo] . [ctbl.Main.Report]                      WHERE Year = left(convert(varchar,getdate(),126),7) AND Site = '7115' and Code in ( '52120','52140','52147','52146','52182' )

Comment: I suggest you read the Microsoft docs. You are not being clear on which server you are executing the query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Example: Server you are running the query on is Server2? and the linked server is sacfindb?

Comment: So, the query is running on Server 1, Server 1 is linked to Server 2. Sacfindb is the internal server.

Comment: Are both Sacfindb and Server2 linked servers on Server 1? And you're attempting to update Server2 using data from Sacfindb and running this on Server 1?

Comment: Yeah, both servers Sacfindb and Server 2 are linked to Server 1 and I am attempting to update the data on Server 2 using data from Sacfindb and running this on Server 1.

Comment: Quick question - are you able to query from Server 1 to both servers: select top 10 year from uc_polog.dbo.ctbl.main.report and also select top 10 year from server2.fleet.dbo.log

Comment: Yes, I am able to query from Server 1 to both the servers. I have made sure they are linked as well.

Comment: Are you trying to update ALL records in Server2 because I don't see any join columns. Also your tables have the same column names so maybe make aliases for your tables and qualify all columns (like UC_Plog table alias as plog then use plog.Year, plog.Site, plog.Code.

Comment: UPDATE [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log] 
SET [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Year] = Poll.[Year],
       [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Site] = Poll.[Site],
       [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Code] = Poll.[Code] 
FROM [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log] AS A
JOIN (SELECT plog.Year, plog.Site, plog.Code  
 FROM [UC_POLog].[dbo].[ctbl.Main.Report] 
 WHERE Year = left(convert(varchar,getdate(),126),7) AND Site = '7115' AND Code in ('52120','52140','52147','52146','52182')) Poll
ON plog.Year = A.Year

Comment: So I have made some changes but now I am getting the error that my linked server does not contain [Fleet].[dbo].[log]

Comment: I would create a new question or edit this one and include your full sql code and the full details of connection (Running the query from Server 1, linked servers are [X] and [Y]) and also the full error code.

Comment: There is not enough characters to enter the entire code

Comment: Create a NEW QUESTION.

Comment: Ok here the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323812/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound-error-servers-have-already-been-li