# "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" error, but servers have already been linked

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update data from one server to the server. There are three columns, *Year*, *Site*, and *Code*, that need to be updated from my current server (Server 1) to Server 2.

However, I keep getting the error of:

> The multi-part identifier could not be bound.

Below is my query (Server 1 is linked to both the Server 2 and sacfindb):

```
UPDATE [Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log]
SET
[Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Year] = Poll.[Year],
[Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Site] = Poll.[Site],
[Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log].[Code] = Poll.[Code]
FROM (SELECT Year, Site, Code
    FROM sacfindb.[UC_POLog].[dbo].[ctbl.Main.Report]
    WHERE Year = left(convert(varchar,getdate(),126),7)
        AND Site = '7115'
        AND Code IN (
            '52120','52140','52147','52146','52182'
        )
    ) Poll
```

Comment: *What* multipart identifier? Include the **full** error. Also, you should really avoid 3+ part naming for columns; support for it is due to be remvoed from SQL Server.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Server2.Fleet.dbo.log" could not be bound.

Comment: I don't think you have any logic there to do an `update`.  How will it know *which* row to update?  Are you sure you don't want `insert`?

Comment: Basically I want to be updating the data from my current server daily to Server 2

Comment: Does your subquery only return 1 row then, and you want ***every*** row in the table `[Server2].[Fleet].[dbo].[log]` to have the same value of `Year`, `Site` and `Code`? And please put the error in your question, not the comments.

Comment: Also [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: It returns multiple rows, and yes I want every row in the table in server 2 as it will be updated and have the same values for the columns: Year, Site and Code.

Comment: But if it returns mjultiple rows, what value from `sacfindb.[UC_POLog].[dbo].[ctbl.Main.Report]` should a **single** row be updated with? A single row can't have the value of many rows.

Comment: So the site is 7115 right now but later on I will be including all of them. This is just one location.